# Page not found in next.js vercel deployment with strapi in backend

Tags: next.js, strapi, vercel

I have a folder structure like this in my next app

```
├───blogs
│   ├───[slug].js
│   └───index.js
...
```

I published 2 blogs in Strapi. Lets say `firstBlog` and `secondBlog`.

In local everything works fine. But in a deployed app from vercel when I go to details of `firstBlog` everything works fine. But for the `secondBlog` it says 404 not found. I looked for answers but couldn’t find the problem. My slug.js:

```js
import Layout from '../../components/Layout/layout'
import BlogPost from '../../components/Blog/blog'
import api from '../../api'



const Blog = ({ blog }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <BlogPost blog={blog} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const response = await api.getAllBlogs()
  const paths = response.map(path => {
    return {
      params: {slug: path.attributes.slug.toString()}
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}


export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const slug = context.params.slug
  const response = await api.getSingleBlog(slug)
  
  return {
    props: { blog: response }
  }
}


export default Blog
```

and my api call is such as:

```
  getSingleBlog(slug) {
    return this.execute("get", `blogs?filters[slug]=${slug}&populate=categories`);
  },
```

I think this is about my deployment in vercel. But couldn’t find the solution. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is `api.getAllBlogs()` returning the expected output in production?

Comment: Yes, a bit late but yes